# Struts2 JSON Plugin With Annotations

Tags: json, struts2

I have a Struts2 Action Class configured via annotations. All of the "normal" methods that are annotated with @Action work fine.

However, I need to add a method into the action that returns JSON.

Here is a trimmed down version of my class (dao autowired with Spring):

```
@Namespace("featureClass")
// define success and input actions for class here
public class FeatureClassAction extends ActionSupport {

    FeatureClassDao featureClassDao;

    @Autowired
    public setFeatureClassDao(FeatureClassDeao featureClassDao) {
        this.featureClassDao = featureClassDao;
    }

    List<FeatureClass> featureClasses;

    // snip normal actions

    @Action("/featureClassesJSON")
    @JSON
    public String getFeatureClassesJSON() throws Exception {

        featureClasses = featureClassDao.getAll();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist? If I have to go the struts.xml route, that means moving all of my other actions (which work fine) into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured I would share the answer, since anyone else with the same problem would likely also face the silence.

I created two actions: FeatureClassAction and FeatureClassJsonAction. FeatureClassAction was annotated as such:

```
@ParentPackage("struts-default")
@Namespace("/featureClass")
public class FeatureClassAction extends ActionSupport {
```

FeatureClassJsonAction is annotated like this:

```
@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Namespace("/featureClass")
public class FeatureClassJsonAction extends ActionSupport {
```

The method in the JSON Action was annotated like this:

```
@Action(value="featureClassesJson", results = {
    @Result(name="success", type="json")
})

public String getFeatureClassesJSON() throws Exception {
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Can you please let me know what URL you used to access the action? No matter what I tried it just gives me "There is no Action mapped for namespace [/featureClass] and action name [featureClassesJson] associated with context path [/myapp]." I tried http://localhost:8080/myapp/featureClass/featureClassesJson.action and .do and lots of other permutations.

Comment: The url should be featureClass/featureClassesJson.action